# Finding A Basis For Null(A)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be $\begin{pmatrix} 2&1&-4\\3 &5 &-7\\ 4 & -5& -6\end{pmatrix}$


Find a basis to Null(A).

I have brought the matrix to row reduced form, but I keep getting the trivial answer (0,0,0).

and the answer is (13,2,7)

Comment: check your work again, here is the row reduced form from wolfram
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=rref%20%7B%7B2%2C1%2C-4%7D%2C%7B3%2C5%2C-7%7D%2C%7B4%2C-5%2C-6%7D%7D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you row reduced correctly, you'd have

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&\frac{-13}7\\ 0 & 1 & \frac{-2}7\\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Can you take it from here?